# How do I point out the path to Sencha touch lib

Tags: sencha-touch-2

I had to move the lib folder of senchas touch framework. Now I keep getting errors where Sencha look for the framwork in the wrong folder. In which config file do I define the path of the framework? Is it in the hidden `.Sencha`-folder?

New location is `lib/touch/`

Answer (score 0):

You will find and entry inside the {root}/bootstrap.js

```
  "Ext": "touch/src",
```

Around line 4. Change this to your needs

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: Thanks - changed my answer.